# netstat pipe count host

Tags: awk, pipe, netstat

Unix pipe problem: how to process multiline input to output the line and insert some piped processes.

```
echo "111 22222222" | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " piped_processes_using_2nd_argument}'
```

A bit of context: netstat parsed to get the list of external ip adresses connected to $current_ip, sorted decreasingly, for example (not real case):

```
$ netstat -plant |grep $current_ip | tr -s ' ' |cut -f5 -d' '|cut -f1 -d':' |sort -n |uniq -c |sort -nr
   7 8.8.8.8
   2 4.4.4.4
   1 186.2.168.190
   1 207.192.128.2
```

So far, reverse DNS using

```
$ host 4.4.4.4 | tr -s " " | rev  | cut -f1 -d " " |rev
alu7750testscr.xyz1.gblx.mgmt.Level3.net.
```

From these, I want to get something like (yes, keeping the ip in the output):

```
   7 8.8.8.8 google-public-dns-a.google.com.
   2 4.4.4.4 alu7750testscr.xyz1.gblx.mgmt.Level3.net.
   1 186.2.168.190 ddos-guard.net.
   1 207.192.128.2 www.NexQloud.com.
```

To merge these, I could only think of awk, but as I am not fluent with it, the result is very ugly:

```
netstat -plant |grep $current_ip | tr -s ' ' |cut -f5 -d' '|cut -f1 -d':' |sort -n |uniq -c |sort -nr  | awk '{ system("echo " $1 " " $2 " $(host "$2" | tr -s \" \" | rev  | cut -f1 -d \" \" |rev)") }' | sort -nr -k1
```

I want something more elegant and fast enough to get called in a watch --interval=1 :-)

Comment: This looks like one of those situations where I would switch from a huge pipeline to a while/read loop. That way you can assign intermediate variables and output the final fields/variables that you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

you like `|`  do you ?

the best I come with

```
current_ip=$(ifconfig eth0 | awk '$1 == "inet" { split($2,A,":") ; print A[2] ; } ')

netstat -plant | grep $current_ip | awk '{split($5,A,":") ; howmany[A[1]]++ ; }
END { for (h in howmany) printf "%d %s \n",howmany[h],h ;} '|
 sort -nr |
while read hm ho
do
  name=$(host $ho|awk '{print $NF}')
  echo $hm $ho $name
done
```

where

- no need to escape new line, if last char is a pipe
- `{split($5,A,":") ; howmany[A[1]]++ ; }` remember each host and count (after stripping port number)
- `END { for (h in howmany) printf "%d %s \n",howmany[h],h ;}` at the end of netstat, print result
- `name=$(host $ho|awk '{print $NF}')` gethostname from IP
- `use ${name%%.}` to get rid of ending `.`
- add current_ip

not sure my solution is better any way, I only have 4 pipe instead of 12.

Comment: you use bash ? that looks like host is given no argument.

Comment: I assure you this version works ;   running on bash 4.3.33 ;  echo $SHELL   gives  /bin/bash

Comment: in my case, eval current_ip=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | awk '{print $2}' |cut -f2 -d":")

Comment: I edited my answer. less pipe, more awk.

Comment: excellent! lacks some pipes though, but easier to maintain, thank you very much!